# Powershell - invoke-command - if reg exists

Tags: powershell, if-statement, exists, invoke-command

I have wrote that script but the result is the same for all the computer.To be more precise if my device has the registry Name then all have it which does not reflect the reality.Same if my device does have it.
I would need help to understand my mistake.
Thank you in advance

```
$ADSearchBaseComputers = 'ou=computers,ou=xxx,ou=xx,ou=xxx,dc=xx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx'
$computers= get-adcomputer -filter * -searchbase "$ADSearchBaseComputers" | select -Property SamAccountName

foreach ($computer in $computers)
    {
        
        Invoke-Command {    
                            $RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
                            $RegName= Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath -Name MTBLogin 

                            
                            if  ($RegName)
                             {
                             Write-Output "Reg Key presente pour $($computer.SamAccountName)"
                             
                             }

                            else
                            {
                            Write-Output "Reg Key non presente pour $($computer.SamAccountName)"
                            }
                       }
    
    }
```

Initially I had the `$RegPath` and `$RegName` values before the loop so I moved them inside but the result is the same.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this, not using select -expand, using samaccountname instead of name, not telling invoke-command which computer to run the code on.

Comment: I have modified the invoke-commande to Invoke-Command -computer $computer. but it gives an an error Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:7 char:13
+     {       Invoke-Command -computer $computer
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

Comment: @js2010 - I agree with you but I am just starting with Powershell

Comment: I made 2 other corrections.

Comment: edited the script $computers= get-adcomputer -filter * -searchbase "$ADSearchBaseComputers" -properties Name | select -ExpandProperty Name

foreach($computer in $computers)
 
    {       Invoke-Command -computer $computer

Comment: how do I pass on the value of $computer inside the invoke-command ?                             foreach($computer in $computers)
    {Invoke-Command -computer $computer { xxxxxxx
                                    Write-Output "Reg Key presente pour $computer"

Comment: how do I pass on the value of $computer inside the invoke-command ?  the name contained in $computer is not present in the write-output
                                                                                                              foreach($computer in $computers)
    { Invoke-Command -computer $computer {
  $RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
  $RegName= Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath -Name MTBLogin                                  
        if  ($RegName)
          { Write-Output "Reg Key presente pour $computer"}

Comment: found my solution added a new variable in the scriptblock      $DeviceName = $env:computername

Comment: So why use `Write-Output` and add a new variable inside the scriptblock? Have it output a PsCustomObject instead with properties 'KeyPresent' (value $true or $false) and another property 'ComputerName' (value = $env:ComputerName). BTW. Invoke-Command can handle an array of computernames, so no need to loop over them one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it something like this.  Giving invoke-command the whole array of computernames will make it run in parallel.  If you return an object, you'll get the pscomputername automatically.  It should give a result whether the registry entry is there or not.

```
$ADSearchBaseComputers = 'ou=computers,ou=xxx,ou=xx,ou=xxx,dc=xx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx'
$computers= get-adcomputer -filter * -searchbase $ADSearchBaseComputers |
  select -ExpandProperty Name
Invoke-Command $computers {    
  $RegPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'
  $RegName = Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath -Name MTBLogin
  [pscustomobject]@{RegName = [boolean]$RegName}
}

RegName PSComputerName RunspaceId
------- -------------- ----------
   True COMP001        d4124bfd-f3d1-4af0-b065-1607627f224a
   True COMP002        d4124bfd-f3d1-4af0-b065-1607627f224b
  False COMP003        d4124bfd-f3d1-4af0-b065-1607627f224c
```